# ASP.NET general - What is the topic name of the following?

Tags: asp.net

I am reviewing a code written by the previous programmer in the company I work for, what he is doing is, he is assigning `/?member_id=76` (just for example, he is actually using a unique int for each member), then he is storing the `/?member_id=76` in the database and using it to connect to the dependent of that member so that a member sends a link to his/her dependent with that `/?member_id` so that we know that depdent belongs to the member when the depedent fill in the application.
 Now I am asking to do something similar and I have few questions:

1. what is this topic called in ASP.net?
2. How can I just  take that part of the url? I know how to store it in a session variable but dont know how to take it out, lets say I have `www.mywebsite.com/?member_id=99` I just want `member_id=99` from that link.
3. what is a better way if there is any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Request.QueryString[]
2. Request.Item[]
3. Parse URL with HttpValueCollection (that is not most suitable way).
4. Keep data in session that's possible but not the best way. I prefer to use class property to hold data or cookie.

Answer (score 1):

1) ASP.NET Query Strings.

2) With using

```
String s = Request.QueryString["field1"];
```

as the example in the link below.

3) You can create and use session objects, which i prefer, but there are other ways which you will see in the link below

[More information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)